# Pre-generating proxies for NHibernate 3.x?

Tags: nhibernate, orm, lazy-loading

Is it possible to pre-generate lazy-loading proxies under NHibernate 3?

NHibernate 2 supported this via [NHPG](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/pre-generate-lazy-loading-proxies.aspx) but NHPG hasn't been updated for NH3 that I can see. Downloading the [NHPG sources](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhcontrib/files/NHibernate.ProxyGenerators/1.0.0%20Beta%20621/NHibernate.ProxyGenerators-1.0.0.Beta621-src.zip/download) and blindly changing the assembly reference from NH2 to NH3 blows up; NH3 has built-in proxy generation and stuff has been reorganized.

How are people (pre) generating lazy proxies under NH3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've updated NHPG to support NHibernate 3.3.1 GA.

You could grab the sources here: https://github.com/NHibernate-Contrib/NHibernate.ProxyGenerators

You have to build it by hands (download the sources and run `package.cmd`) for now until we release an official version.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this answers your question since I do not see any tag related to language that you are using.

In .NET, I use [Fluent NHibernate](http://www.fluentnhibernate.org/) and POCO objects. Don't know if there is a tool to upgrade your XML files to POCO classes to use with Fluent NHibernate.

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer is completely off topic and doesn't pertain to anything related to the question. The question is about pre-generating the proxy classes that are typically generated at runtime using C# reflection but if you want to run an NHibernate application in a medium trust environment, you typically cannot use lazy loading as it requires reflection which is not permitted in medium trust hosting environments. The only way to actually get lazy loading is to pre-generate the proxy classes. See this article: http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/pre-generate-lazy-loading-proxies.aspx

Comment: Yes, you're right. You would not be able to use that in medium trust with most hosting providers. Sorry, I do not know any tool to do what you want.